# JSP and HTML - Naming check boxes with different names from a loop

Tags: html, jsp, checkbox

I have something like this in my code

```
<% while (i.hasNext()) {
     Object obj = i.next();
        ...
%>
        ...
     <input type="checkbox" name="ticketCheck"/>
        ...

<% } %>
```

How can I make the names become ticketCheck1, ticketCheck2 etc so I can reference a corresponding object that displays?

Comment: stop putting java code in JSP files.  Use tags, like the JSTL library and the maintenance programmers will stop cursing the day you were born..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming tickets is the collection or array of ticket

```
      <c:forEach var="ticket" items="${tickets}">
        <TR>
           <input type="checkbox" name="${ticket}"/>
        </TR>
      </c:forEach>
```

Comment: You're basically setting `String.valueOf(tickets)` as `items` instead of `tickets`.

Comment: I'm new to JSP and Web application making. This should be fine, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different example.  This assumes that tickets is a list of objects and that for each object there is defined a getValue() and getName() method.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${tickets}">
...
...
<input type="checkbox" value="${item.value}" name="${item.name}"/>
...
...
```